# Removing taskbar thumbnail close button

Tags: windows, visual-studio, aero-peek

In Visual Studio it is possible to remove the "X" in the upper right corner of a window (form) by setting ControlBox to false. However, even with that set to false, there is still a X closing button that shows up in the upper right corner of the taskbar thumbnail (aero peek?). Is there a way to hide that X button as well?